# How can I combine a set of text files, leaving off the first line of each?

Tags: bash, shell, file-io

As part of a normal workflow, I receive sets of text files, each containing a header row. It's more convenient for me to work with these as a single file, but if I `cat` them naively, the header rows in files after the first cause problems.

The files tend to be large enough (10<sup>3</sup>–10<sup>5</sup> lines, 5–50 MB) and numerous enough that it's awkward and/or tedious to do this in an editor or step-by-step, e.g.:

```
$ wc -l *
    20251 1.csv
   124520 2.csv
    31158 3.csv
   175929 total

$ tail -n 20250 1.csv > 1.tmp

$ tail -n 124519 2.csv > 2.tmp

$ tail -n 31157 3.csv > 3.tmp

$ cat *.tmp > combined.csv

$ wc -l combined.csv
175926 combined.csv
```

It seems like this should be doable in one line. I've isolated the arguments that I need but I'm having trouble figuring out how to match them up with `tail` and subtract 1 from the line total (I'm not comfortable with `awk`):

```
$ wc -l * | grep -v "total" | xargs -n 2
20251 foo.csv
124520 bar.csv
31158 baz.csv
87457 zappa.csv
7310 bingo.csv
29968 niner.csv
2086 hella.csv

$ wc -l * | grep -v "total" | xargs -n 2 | tail -n
tail: option requires an argument -- n
Try 'tail --help' for more information.
xargs: echo: terminated by signal 13
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `wc -l` to calculate the number of lines to output; `tail` can skip the first line (or the first K lines), just by adding a `+` symbol when using the `-n` (or `--lines`) option, as described in the man page:

```
  -n, --lines=K            output the last K lines, instead of the last 10;
                             or use -n +K to output starting with the Kth
```

This makes combining all files in a directory without the first line of each file as simple as:

```
$ tail -q -n +2 * > combined.csv

$ wc -l *
    20251 foo.csv
   124520 bar.csv
    31158 baz.csv
    87457 zappa.csv
     7310 bingo.csv
    29968 niner.csv
     2086 hella.csv
   302743 combined.csv
   605493 total
```

The `-q` flag suppresses headers in the output when globbing for multiple files with `tail`.

Comment: apropos extra lines tail outputs when dealing with multiple files, passing `-q` should fix that

Comment: @1_CR Good tip. Feel like adding an answer or shall I incorporate it into this one?

Comment: please incorporate and give me the pleasure of upvoting your answer:-)

Comment: Don't use `ls` here; just use `tail -qn +2 *`.

Answer (score 3):

Both `tail` and `sed` answers work fine.

For the sake of an alternative here is an `awk` command that does the same job:

```
awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv > combined.csv
```

`FNR > 1` condition will skip first row for each file.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -ns '2,$p' 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv > combined.csv
```

or

```
sed -ns '2,$p' *.csv > combined.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` alternative

```
    sed -s 1d *.csv
```

deletes first line from each input file, without `-s` it will only delete from the first file.